# Access a Windows Azure WCF Services on a Windows Phone 7 Device on a local development machine

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, iis, azure

How do I access a Windows Azure WCF Services on a Windows Phone 7 Device on a local development machine. I've tried my local IP and also switched off my firewall. Nothing helps. Do we have any cool hacks for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you're trying to access the emulator on your development machine with a real Windows Phone device? Officially this isn't supported, since the emulator only accepts local connections. But you can use the port forwarding features available in Windows to bypass this limitation:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8081 connectport=81 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

Now, instead of having your WP7 connect to **yourip:81** you should configure the device to connect to **yourip:8081**.